# job execution in SSIS fails

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have one job(report generation) which runs once in day for whole month but its running properly till 24th date of month after that it is giving below error.Pls provide solution asap.

Highlighted the error below For your reference

> ERROR:
>   Executed as user: MMKNDJAVADB\Administrator. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.4000.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:00:00 AM  Error: 2016-03-25 11:01:18.53     **Code: 0xC0047018     Source: Get DMS Invoice Data SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "ADO NET Source" (16) failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004002.  End Error  Error: 2016-03-25 11:01:18.53     Code: 0xC0047018     Source: Get DMS Invoice Data SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "ADO NET Source" (16) failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004002.  End Error  Error: 2016-03-25 11:01:59.91     Code: 0xC0047062     Source: Get DMS Cancellation Data ADO NET Source 1 [1]     Description: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HYT00] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)**     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)  End Error  Error: 2016-03-25 11:01:59.91     Code: 0xC004701A     Source: Get DMS Cancellation Data SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "ADO NET Source 1" (1) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80131937.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  11:00:00 AM  Finished: 11:02:00 AM  Elapsed:  119.532 seconds.  The package executed successfully.  The step succeeded.

Comment: when editing the question,i saw this ..user requested cancel of current operation..This is not an error

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the timeout in the "Get DMS Invoice Data" in the ADO. NET component - data source of your data. Should help.

Comment: by default 30 seconds only

Comment: Try changing it to 0.

Comment: Great. I am happy to hear this. If you are OK please mark my answer as correct solution